# Sample textures from array into Voronoi cells

Tags: arrays, shader, textures, fragment-shader, voronoi

https://ibb.co/82WMNCt

I wrote a fragment shader that samples a different texture for each voronoi cell. Right now I loop through all positions for each pixel, which is super inefficient.

Any tipps on how to optimize this? I need to run 2 x 1080p with 1000 "cells" - which is my cpu max for box2d.

maybe draw the cells within vertex shader and then sample on them? I am quite new to this, any hints appreciated!

weird sizing (*20 etc) due to my large box2d world for testing.

cheers, A

```
Texture2DArray texArray <string uiname="Texture Array";>;
Texture2D tex <string uiname="Texture";>;

int id;
int scale= 20;

float4x4 tWVP: WORLDVIEWPROJECTION;

SamplerState linearSampler : IMMUTABLE
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

cbuffer cbPerDraw : register( b0 )
{
    float4x4 tVP : LAYERVIEWPROJECTION; 
};

cbuffer cbPerObj : register( b1 )
{
    float4x4 tW : WORLD;
};

StructuredBuffer<float2> posBuffer;
StructuredBuffer<int> idBuffer;

struct vsInput
{
    float4 PosO : POSITION;
    float4 TexCd : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct psInput
{
    float4 PosWVP: SV_Position;
    float4 TexCd: TEXCOORD0;
};

psInput VS(vsInput In)
{
    return In;  
}


float4 PS(psInput In): SV_Target
{
    uint count, stride;
    posBuffer.GetDimensions(count, stride); 

    float minDist = 100;
    float2 uvRaw = In.TexCd.xy;
    float2 uv = ( uvRaw -.5) * 20;
    float4 col = 1;
    uint id;

    for (uint i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        id = idBuffer[i];
        float2 p = posBuffer[i]*1;
        float d = length(uv-p) * .2;

        if (d < minDist)
        {
            minDist = d;
            col = texArray.SampleLevel(linearSampler, float3(uvRaw - p *0.05, i), 0);
        }       
    }   
    return col;      
}


technique10 Constant
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_5_0, VS() ) );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_5_0, PS() ) );
    }
}


  [1]: https://ibb.co/82WMNCt
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common optimization for generating Voronoi noise is to divide the texture into a grid with 1 point in each cell, find the grid cell of the current fragment, and then only compare the distance against this cell and its 8 neighbors. So basically, you should be able to store your points in a 2D array, and then find the cell index by dividing and flooring the UVs using the cell size. Sebastian Lague touched on this in his video on cloud rendering, you can check it out [here](https://youtu.be/4QOcCGI6xOU?t=117), he also made the source code available on GitHub.